# Regular expression match first meet

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
xxx [[a]] yyy [[b]] zzz
```

How to write a regex to return 2 result with `[[a]]` and `[[b]]`

regex like `\[\[.+\]\]` only return 1 result `[[a]] yyy [[b]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantifiers are by default greedy in nature. They would consume as much as they can. Since `.` matches any character, `.+` will match as much number of characters as it can, and it will stop only before the last `]]`.

You should use reluctant quantifier (`.+?`), which will match only till the first occurrence of `]]`:

```
\[\[.+?\]\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-greedy quantifier `+?`. http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Moreover, I would better use the negated character class

```
`\[\[[^\]]+\]\]`
```

if in between your couples of square brackets you are sure there is not a closing square bracket. The use of `.` should be avoided if you know what you can find and what you want to match.

Comment: Negated class not needed. .*? is ok cos only match if followed by two ]

Comment: @Bohemian - When using delimiters, thats something that should probably be avoided. `.*?` only suggests non-greedy to the engine.

Comment: It's OK, but I can't think of a situation where it would help here. Just an observation

Comment: Really? Even in the case of unbalanced text? It is supposedly delimeters, depends on intent I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would think for safety, its better to be more specific on the body of the brackets.
For example [[ `[a-z]+` ]]  or, [[ `[^\[\]]+` ]].

It looks like you're using the paired double brackets `[[` - `]]` as delimeters.

In general, you should never use the form [[ `.+?` ]] in any broader regex context.
Because even though it looks non-greedy, the engine will turn it greedy at anytime
depending on the surrounding expression and the string it is matching against.

For example,

```
  string = '  this is [[XX]] and here is [[ZZ]] end  '
  regex  = '\[\[.+?\]\]\s*end'

  match  = '[[XX]] and here is [[ZZ]] end'
```